# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar de nombre a un checkbox en vba?

Tags: vba

Private Sub CheckBoxtodo_Click()

```
If Me.CheckBoxtodo = True Then
    
    Me.CheckBox1.Value = True
              .
              .
              .
    Me.CheckBox28.Value = True
   Else
    Me.CheckBox1.Value = False
             .
             .
             .
    Me.CheckBox28.Value = FALSE
End If
```

End Sub

Quisiera hacer un for al cual valla iterando y solo poner el nombre el cual concatenare con la variable de iteración hasta llegar al Checkbox28 e ir cambiando su valor
soy nuevo en esto de VBA espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Debes ir a la ventana de propiedades (F4 si no está) para poder cambiarle el nombre, seleccionas el checkbox que quieras cambiarle el nombre, y en esa ventana te deja cambiarle el nombre para poder referirte a él como quieras.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder pero creo que no puse bien el titulo lo que en realidad buscaba era llamar a varios objetos checkbox y cambiar su valor segun el valor de una celda

Answer (score 0):

Despues de buscar por foros encontre la solucion a lo que quiero y por fin lo pude lograr con este codigo:

```
[![Private Sub CheckBoxtodo_Click()
Dim ctrl As OLEObject
Dim check As MSForms.CheckBox
If Me.CheckBoxtodo = True Then
    For Each ctrl In Worksheets(2).OLEObjects
        If TypeOf ctrl.Object Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
        Set check = ctrl.Object
          For i = 1 To Hoja2.Range("B3").Value
                If LCase(check.Caption) = "" & i Then
                    check.Enabled = True
                    ctrl.Visible = True
                    check.Value = True
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next
Else
    For Each ctrl In Worksheets(2).OLEObjects
        If TypeOf ctrl.Object Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
        Set check = ctrl.Object
          For i = 1 To 28
                If LCase(check.Caption) = "" & i Then
                    check.Enabled = True
                    ctrl.Visible = True
                    check.Value = False
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next
End If
    Range("H3").Select
End Sub][1]][1]
```

[image: objetos en Vba]

los checkbox tienen como Caption los valores del 1 al 28.